# Showing a rank based on score

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, ranking, scoring

I've been trying to get this bit of code to work, but have had not luck. I'm trying to have it print a certain rank, based on the "handicap" score, but it seems to just randomly print a rank. I have code the successfully figures out the handicap, but once I get to my if statements trying to print the score, it seems to just randomly print the text.

```
            If (Handicap < 0) Then
                TxtRank.Text = "Championship"
            ElseIf (0 > Handicap Or Handicap < 5) Then
                TxtRank.Text = "Duffer"
            ElseIf (5 < Handicap Or Handicap < 10) Then
                TxtRank.Text = "Average"
            ElseIf (Handicap > 10) Then
                TxtRank.Text = "Hacker"
            End If
```

Comment: you do know VS comes with a powerful debugger which allows you to examine your code as it executes, right?  Those second 2 tests dont make much sense. Select the first line, press [F9].  Then run the code and see what is really happening.

Comment: At least some of your comparisons ought to be <= instead of <.  If the handicap is exactly 5, for example, none of the if criteria will be satisfied and the text won't be changed.  Also, "0 > Handicap" ought to be "0 < Handicap" (or <=).

Comment: Just a hint, if **it is possible for you** _to change the variable types used by your application_ : avoid using `String` when you have a defined list of states. Use `Enums` instead, much much faster...

Answer (score 2):

When testing a variable for multiple values like this it is easier to use a Select Case statement.

The reason why you are having issues is because you have not catered for all possible values and your logic is conflicting for certain values e.g. `0 > Handicap Or Handicap < 5`.

```
    Select Case Handicap
        Case Is < 0
            TxtRank.Text = "Championship"
        Case Is < 5
            TxtRank.Text = "Duffer"
        Case Is < 10
            TxtRank.Text = "Average"
        Case Else
            TxtRank.Text = "Hacker"
    End Select
```

Comment: It may be easier, but it won't handle a value of 4.5 whereas the OP's original code (if it worked) would. Jus' sayin' like ...

Comment: @TheBlueDog - fair comment - I have modified the answer to cope with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many useless options that make it hard to read. Try this:

```
        If (Handicap < 0) Then
            TxtRank.Text = "Championship"
        ElseIf Handicap < 5 Then
            TxtRank.Text = "Duffer"
        ElseIf Handicap < 10 Then
            TxtRank.Text = "Average"
        Else
            TxtRank.Text = "Hacker"
        End If
```